# If I called the police and told them I drove at 56 for a few seconds on a 55 mph road, what would happen?

Tags: police, traffic, driving, oregon, speeding

Suppose I call the police and confess that, while driving on a road with a 55 MPH speed limit, I drove at 56 for a few seconds. They did nothing to prompt it; I just randomly decided to do it (but I had indeed "sped," if this is even speeding) What would happen?

Comment: They'd probably tell you to stop wasting their time...

Comment: They need to _proof_ that you exceeded the speed limit. Your number 56 is just a guess and not proof, even if it was true. But it depends on how much humour they have. I would find it very funny to send you a speeding ticket, which means you have the choice to pay or go to court. I think the law question is “How much trouble can the police officer cause me without getting into trouble themselves".

Comment: I they wanted to take action they wouldn't need proof because they have your confession. Of course if you changed your mind about the confession before the case went to court then that would make the prosecution difficult. Which is merely one of the many, many reasons why they will take no action.

Comment: @DJClayworth Usually yes. If you confess something then (apart from some idiots who confess to murders for whatever reasons) then you did it. But confession "I drove 56" only means "I drove, and my speedometer showed 56". Which doesn't prove you drove 56. Admit to driving 60, and you're right. Say a wife confesses "I killed my husband" and six weeks later he comes out of hospital. The confession is good evidence she hit him badly enough to think he died, but she was clearly wrong and not a murderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might tell you that under [ORS 810.410](https://oregon.public.law/statutes/ors_810.410)

> (2) A police officer may issue a citation to a person for a traffic
> violation at any place within or outside the jurisdictional authority
> of the governmental unit by which the police officer is authorized to
> act: (a) When the traffic violation is committed in the police
> officer’s presence; or (b) When the police officer has probable cause
> to believe an offense has occurred based on a description of the
> vehicle or other information received from a police officer who
> observed the traffic violation

and therefore they would instruct you to have a police officer witness the speeding next time.

You could petition the court to be allowed to fill in the citation form, and depending on the county, the petition might be granted.

Answer (score 6):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

They would laugh at you and possibly send out someone to make a mental health welfare check.

Answer (score 1):

## If you filmed it and drove dangerous and put it to video, then they might act.

There's this stunt driver who, under the name of Ghost Rider in a black motorcycle combi was flaunting traffic laws [all over Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Rider_(motorcyclist)). They put videos of their exploits on sale. Because of this, police not only have a proof for the traffic infractions, they wanted to find out the identity of the driver so they can find them for the acts. The [Swiss Police](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3465842/The-Ghost-Rider-caught-Police-arrest-biker-taunted-posting-videos-YouTube-racing-140mph-Swiss-roads.html) did get him, some others did snatch him at times. Eventually he quit the act. [One person alleged to be Ghost Rider now is a Subaru salesman in Stockholm.](https://www.hotcars.com/heres-what-happened-to-the-suzuki-hayabusa-ghost-rider/)

Comment: my question was about driving 1 MPH over the speed limit.

Comment: I remember "the black knight of Paris" who managed to record driving the motorway around Paris on a motorbike in record time, filming himself, and the time required to go more than  twice the motorway speed limit on average. In other words, totally insane. Also impossible due to traffic in any car.